# How to configure http response code in ajax, using php and cors?

Tags: php, ajax, cors

i'm setting up a webpage that ask, using ajax (jquery), to a php page some informations and i need different http response code depending on the result.
I've registered a domain on one.com and when i uploaded my filse i noticed that ajax request didn't work properly because of CORS.

I bypassed this problem adding in the .htaccess the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

After that i didn't have problems anymore about CORS.
I've tryied all website functions and i discovered that any http response from the php page return the code 200.

I don't want this because i need different http codes because ajax, depending on the result, prints a message to advise me, but if it recives always 200 it will print always a success tough there was an error on the server (like wrong credentials login).

This is my ajax function for example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://domain/page.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(json),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    async: true,
    statusCode: {
        500: function() {
            //server error
        },
        400: function() {
            //wrong credentials
        },
        200: function() {
            //success
        }
    }
});
```

And this is my php function that shoulds response different codes:

```
response(400,"Wrong credentials");

function response($code,$val){
    if($val){
        print(json_encode($val,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
        http_response_code($code);
    }else{
        http_response_code($code);
    }
}
```

I know there is something called CORS preflight or something else that before your ajax request it sends an OPTIONS one to verify the origin, but i need that the code 200 response from this request does not go in conflict with ajax `statusCode` 200.

Comment: Hmm, there is no reason you should be getting 200's, even cross-origin, if your request is outputting different codes. To identify the issue, I would eliminate the CORS aspect of the equation and see if you get the right codes when making the requests on the same server as the PHP lives.

Comment: Deleting CORS in the .htaccess i can not send any ajax request using JSON.

Comment: What I'm saying is remove CORS from the equation just from testing, and run the requests local to the domain being called. That way we can see what the response codes are when the code runs locally (relatively to the domain being called) and either rule in or rule out CORS as having to do anything with the problem. Simple debugging - remove aspects until you reduce the problem to its causitive components.